Maximum of Light Absorption v/s Color of Complex
I was reading about how d-d transitions cause colour in coordination complexes from my book in the section '$9.5.5$ Colour in Coordination Compounds'. I got surprised by the table of complementary colours drawn there as it stated that the complementary colour of blue-green is red at $500$ nm and violet at $498$ nm.

How does a difference of a couple of nanometres in the wavelength of the colour of light absorbed yield a much bigger difference in the wavelengths of the corresponding complementary colours?

The colour of light absorbed does match the wavelengths given, but the right hand column seems to give the colour we perceive after the absorbed light is removed from, presumably, white light.

@porphyrin yes you are correct.

Please give feedback on the question if it is poorly written so that I can improve it, instead of downvoting without any explanation.

There tends to be quite a lot of down voting for no good reason and for a while now, rather than encouraging someone who has a query. Take no notice, your question is ok. Around the 520 to 600 nm region ones eyes are very sensitive to small wavelength changes, and much less so out side this region. One perceives colour by a mixture of wavelengths and how much some wavelengths are missing vs others, its not an obvious process.

Anyway, it is difficult to understand how two violet substances (number 1 and 6) have two rather different wavelengths of absorption maxima : 535 and 498 nm. Simultaneously, substance no.2 has a wavelength of absorption maximum situated between the two previous values : 500 nm. So it should have the same violet colour. But no ! It has a different color : red instead of violet

About those color regions of absorbed and complementary colors, there are no sharp switches, there are rather transitions. Note that the very right column has the header "Colour of coordination entity", not "Complementary colour".
You can see in the $\ce{[Co(CN)6]^3-}$ example that the maximum absorption is at $\ce{310 nm}$, but it must absorb in violet region $\pu{400-430 nm}$ too to get pale yellow. (It could be also fluorescence, but this can be distinguished by non-axial measurement.)

The ideas you follow are applicable rather on line absorption spectrum of gaseous atoms in AAS, or for narrow absorption bands of some chemical bonds (often in gaseous state).
Aqueous metal complexes (or generally most dissolved colored compounds like organic dyes) have one or few rather broad absorption peaks, often merged. The given wavelength is just the wavelength of maximal absorption and says nothing about the absorption spectrum shape.
As the result, the same numerical values (assumed belonging to the same complementary spectrum and color) can be related to a (very) different absorption spectrum and the complementary transmitted spectrum, leading to different perceived color.
An absorption spectrum with longer-wavelength shoulder much broader than the shorter-wavelength shoulder would visually behave like the maximum was at longer wavelength than the true maximum. And vice versa. Things may get more complicated if there are two maxima.
